# php strips [[:char_class:]] from the string

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

When concatenating mysql regex character classes in php they disappear from the resulting string i.e.:

```php
$regexp_arr = array('(word1)', '(word2)');
$value = 'word3';
$regexp_str = implode('[[:space:]]', $regexp_arr);
$v1 = '[[:<:]](' . $value . ')';

echo $regexp_str;
// gives
'(word1)(word2)';
// instead of 
'(word1)[[:space:]](word2)'

echo $v1;
// gives
'(word3)' 
//instead of 
'[[:<:]](word3)'
```

I've tried with double quotation marks *"*, the result still the same.

Is there a special way to concatenate this in php? Why are the `'[[:char_class:]]'` getting stripped?

server php version is 5.6.36

Comment: Works for me.  https://3v4l.org/vkhb6

Comment: server php version is 5.6.36 . Can that have something to do?

Comment: no, it has nothing do to with php version. result is the same with all versions since 4.3.0 (and I'm sure that it would be the same in 4.0.0 and possibly even in PHP 3)
Probably you have some code which strips those square brackets, could it be some bbcode parser?

Comment: I'm on Modx cms. while I can understand that there could be some stripping for html output, the script operates directly on the database and after that shows the output. Gotta dig under the hood a little then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MODX, `[[` and `]]` are special characters used to [indicate they are tags MODX needs to process](https://docs.modx.org/current/en/building-sites/tag-syntax). Even when you `echo` or retrieve it from the database, MODX will process them when rendering.

For debugging, you can follow-up your echo with an `exit()`.

```php
echo $regexp_str;
exit();
```

That short-circuits MODX and gives you the actual value of the string including the square brackets.

If you want the value to be visible in a MODX-rendered resource or template, then you'll have to replace them with their html entities first:

```php
$regexp_str = str_replace(['[',']'], ['&#91;', '&#93;'], $regexp_str);
```